# How we can combine multiple rows in a single row in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I need to combine this multiple tuples in a single one using Pig script. Could you please provide some guidelines?

```
dump requestFile;
```

**Current Output**

```
(Logging Transaction ID:21214,/var/log/tibco/,NESS-A-1-LPNameRequesttoNESS.log,tibcoTest log)

(Default Data:LP Name Request Message Executed Successfully)

(LoanPath Request ID:  88128640)

(RequestGroupID#:   )

(SplitCount#:  2 )

(SplitIndex:  1)

(Correlation ID : 88128640-1 )
```

**Desired output**

```
(Logging Transaction ID:21214,/var/log/tibco/,NESS-A-1-LPNameRequesttoNESS.log,tibcoTest log,Default Data:LP Name Request Message Executed Successfully,LoanPath Request ID:  88128640,RequestGroupID#:   ,SplitCount#:  2,SplitIndex:  1)
(Correlation ID : 88128640-1 )
```

Comment: What is the criteria for grouping a set of rows together?  Is this data the result of a set of operations in pig?  If that's the case, maybe you should be grouping them earlier in your pig script.

Comment: You could try a Pig UDF (Written in Java) suiting your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
requestFile = foreach requestFile generate flatten(tuple);
G = GROUP requestFile ALL;
F = FOREACH G generate requestFile;
```